# Unexpected ambiguous redirect in bash script if connecting through ssh to server itself

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I execute scripts, for example one of them is below.
It work property as I expected. The file will send to remote PC and all output of copying, include possible error will store in file with extension log.

```
#!/bin/bash
scp /tmp/v8_8PcnYL_41.sh evgeniy@Ubuntu-VM2:/tmp/v8_8PcnYL_44.sh >> "/tmp/v8_8PcnYL_42.log" 2>&1
```

But, it wont work if execution PC and ssh server is same PC. In this case i get a error ": ambigous redirect 1",
BUT if i execute 2nd line just in the terminal there is no error and operation will execute as expected.
So, why it happens? And what to do in this case?

Ubuntu 18.04, also 22.04

To better understanding here is console output:

```
evgeniy@Ubuntu-VM2:~$ sudo su usr1cv8
[sudo] Enter password for evgeniy:
$ cat /tmp/v8_8PcnYL_43.sh
#!/bin/bash
scp /tmp/v8_8PcnYL_41.sh evgeniy@Ubuntu-VM2:/tmp/v8_8PcnYL_44.sh >> "/tmp/v8_8PcnYL_42.log" 2>&1
$ ls -lha /tmp/v8_8PcnYL_43.sh
-rwxr-x--x 1 usr1cv8 grp1cv8 111 сен 28 20:34 /tmp/v8_8PcnYL_43.sh
$ bash /tmp/v8_8PcnYL_43.sh
: ambiguous redirect 1
$
$ scp /tmp/v8_8PcnYL_41.sh evgeniy@Ubuntu-VM2:/tmp/v8_8PcnYL_44.sh >> "/tmp/v8_8PcnYL_42.log" 2>&1
$ cat /tmp/v8_8PcnYL_42.log
$ exit
evgeniy@Ubuntu-VM2:~$ cat /tmp/v8_8PcnYL_44.sh
#!/bin/bash
cd ~/
/opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S CHECK -U sa -P [hidden] -h -1 -b -Q "SELECT name FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases"
exit $?
evgeniy@Ubuntu-VM2:~$
```

Comment: Are you sure that's **exactly** the command you're running and you aren't using any variables in it or spaces in the file names?

Comment: Maybe this is beside the point, but Ubuntu 18.04 reached the end of standard support on May 31, so you should upgrade unless you have ESM.

Comment: `evgeniy@Ubuntu-**VM2**` .. Does this mean Virt Machine 2? Is Docker or some hypervisor also involved? If so update your Q. Good luck.

Comment: @EdMorton, Yes, I am absolutely sure and I present the script here as it is.

Comment: @wjandrea, it also happens on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: @shellter, Yes Ubuntu-VM2 is short DNS name of virtual machine running on hypervisor under Windows 10. I can use instead of it direct ip address, like 192.162.0.113 and the result will be same.

Comment: I wonder if you might have CRs at the end of the lines in your script. That could possibly explain both why it's failing and why the first part of the usual error message output up to the `:` is missing. Please run `cat -A /tmp/v8_8PcnYL_43.sh` and then [edit] your question to show the output.

Comment: @EdMorton, You are Genius! The ending lines was really CRLF. I changed it's on Linux LF style and script executed correctly. So what is good for REDOS Linux is bad for Ubuntu. Thank U a lot

Comment: `CRLF`, ha! #1 on the [Before asking about problematic code](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) list (-; Too bad this link isn't more readily available . Glad you solved your problem, but voting to close as a typo. Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter, You absolutely right and it sorrow I know it, the program i wrote is cross platform, and in one line I missed the parameter, which must replace line endings

Comment: AFIK, `scp` does not write anything to stdout. What's the point in redirecting it?

Comment: @user1934428, no, you wrong if the error occurred it will be wrote to stterr.
For example: 
check@MSI-01:/etc/systemd/system$ scp /tmp/v8_8PcnYL_41.sh evgeniy@Ubuntu-VM2:/tmp/v8_8PcnYL_44.sh
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ubuntu-vm2: Name or service not known
lost connection

Comment: That's what I said: `scp` does not write anything to **stdout**. Of course it writes error messages to stderr, but since your code does not catch stderr, this is of no relevance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The script has DOS line endings. The big clue was the error message:

```
: ambiguous redirect 1
```

is missing the part that usually comes before the `:` identifying the tool producing the message and the string that is causing the error, e.g.:

```
$ x='foo bar'
$ echo stuff > $x
bash: $x: ambiguous redirect

$ echo stuff > $x$'\r'
': ambiguous redirect
```

See [Why does my tool output overwrite itself and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45772525/why-does-my-tool-output-overwrite-itself-and-how-do-i-fix-it) for more info on DOS line endings and how to fix them.